# Is there a generalization (surely there is) of this simple combinatorial identity?

Tags: soft-question, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities

I was just doing some algebra on a paper and obtained: $$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} {{n+l} \choose l}={2n \choose {n+1}}$$

Are there some generalizations of this identity?

One possible generalization would be $$F_m(n)=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} {{n+l} \choose l}^{m}$$ but it is not in my reach to obtain what would $F_m(n)$ equal to for every $m \in \mathbb N$

Other possible generalization could be of the form $$G_k(n)=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} k^l \cdot{{n+l} \choose l}$$

I am interested in any generalization(s), not neccessarily of the forms I mentioned (I could mention some other forms but so could you so there is no need to do that).

You do not need to prove in an answer a generalization that you mention but it would be nice if you would point me to a direction where that generalization is mentioned and proven.

I asked a same question on MSE and received neither a comment nor an answer so I deleted that question there and decided to ask it here, although this is a low-level question for MO.

Comment: Favourited. I swear I've seen this before. ETA: An answer below beat me to it.

Comment: Note: your last expression can also be written as $$(1-k)^{-(n+1)} \left(1-\frac{(2 n)! B_k(n,n+1)}{n! (n-1)!}\right),$$ where $B$ is the incomplete beta function.

Answer (score 9):

What about the generalised [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity):
$$
{ n_1+\dots +n_p \choose m }= \sum_{k_1+\cdots +k_p = m} {n_1\choose k_1} {n_2\choose k_2} \cdots {n_p\choose k_p}
$$

See also [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) and [Identities involving binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients).

Comment: The hockey-stick identity is indeed a generalization of the identity in question. But how does the identity in question quickly follow from the Vandermonde identity?

Comment: @IosifPinelis if take $p=2$ and use $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ and relabel some indices you get the identity in your post.

Comment: I KNEW I'VE SEEN THIS BEFORE! Great answer!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : I still don't see see it. In the Vandermonde identity, the upper indices $n_i$ are fixed, and the lower indices $k_i$ vary. In the OP's identity, the upper index varies. Can you add to your answer full details of the derivation of the OP's identity from the Vandermonde one?

Answer (score 6):

Since $\binom{n+l}{l} = \binom{n+l}n$, we have
$$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \binom{n+l}{l} = \sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} \binom{i}{n}.$$
Here the lower and upper summation bounds as well as the lower index of binomial coefficients depend on $n$. This is a particular case of a more general formula, where all three entities are independent:
$$\sum_{i=n}^m \binom{i}{k} = \binom{m+1}{k+1} - \binom{n}{k+1}.$$

Comment: Isn't your identity equivalent to the hockey-stick identity (without loss of generality you can take $n=k$ in your 2nd displayed identity)?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Yes, one can be easily obtained from the other.

Answer (score 5):

Formula 4.2.5.37 on page 503 in [Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev](http://download.library1.org/get/CBAA42E62EE2B774D414352E56B8DED6/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%90.%D0%9F.%2C%20%D0%91%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%AE.%D0%90.%2C%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%9E.%D0%98.-%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B.%20%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8.%20%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%201-%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%97%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%A2%20%282002%29.djvu) is 
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{a+k}a\binom{b-k}{b-n}=\binom{a+b+1}n. 
\end{equation}
Substituting here $a=n+1$ and $b=n$, and then replacing $n$ by $n-1$, we get your identity.

The book [Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev](http://download.library1.org/get/CBAA42E62EE2B774D414352E56B8DED6/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%90.%D0%9F.%2C%20%D0%91%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%AE.%D0%90.%2C%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%9E.%D0%98.-%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B.%20%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8.%20%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%201-%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%97%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%A2%20%282002%29.djvu) is in Russian, but this should be no problem here.

Comment: These formulas are essentially the same: formula 4.2.5.36 is obtained from formula 4.2.5.37 by replacement $b$ with $b+n$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev : That's right, thank you. :-)